# C++ pointer to variable within if statement

Tags: c++, pointers, stack

The behavior of the code below surprises me:

```
map<string,long>* map_ptr;
if(true){
    map<string, long> my_map;
    my_map["a"] = 1;
    my_map["b"] = 2;
    my_map["c"] = 3;
    map_ptr = &my_map;
}

//works ONLY IF this for loop comes before the next for loop
for(map<string, long>::iterator itr = map_ptr->begin(); itr != map_ptr->end(); ++itr)
    cout << itr->second << endl; 

// does not work prints random bits
for(map<string, long>::iterator itr = map_ptr->begin(); itr != map_ptr->end(); ++itr)
    cout << itr->first << endl;
```

I knew variables created within if statement only have scope within it, but I thought declaring a pointer to them will work. I have limited knowledge about the stack structure of this code, but I thought the variables, though out of scope, are still on the stack so they still exist. But it seems there's more happening than I know of. What surprised me the most is why the first for loop prints out things correctly, but only if it is executed before the second for loop. I guess it has something to do with the type because `long` is built-in where as `string` is not, but this is far from sufficing to explain to what's going on.

Please help me understand this code. Thanks!

Comment: Once a variable goes out of scope, *don't try to access it*! It's dead and gone (even though the compiler may not have actually cleaned it all up yet).

Comment: where is that post about hotel keys...

Comment: [It's here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794)

Answer (score 5):

The code has undefined behaviour, meaning anything can happen including appearing to work, as `map_ptr` is a dangling pointer as `my_map` will be destructed at the closing `}` of the `if`. The `map_ptr` will retain the *address* of `my_map` but this does not affect the lifetime of `my_map` in anyway.